# C++, comment in a multi-line piece of code

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, comments

Shouldn't the code:

```
int Func(int a, // comment
         int b, // comment
         int c  // comment
        ) ...
```

be equivalent to:

```
int Func(int a, // comment int b, // comment int c  // comment) ...
```

Why does it build correctly (at least with G++)?

So far, I always used `/* */` comments in such cases.

Comment: a comment which begins with `//` ends with a newline. That's just the way the language is.

Comment: What would make you think the two are equivalent?

Comment: No it should not

Comment: Preprocessor doesn't know anything about your code

Comment: The only place, where I would never use the one-line comment style (`//`) is in macros: [Strange Example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95799cbd03e9bdac).

Comment: Where do you think a `//` comment ends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int Func(int a, // comment
         int b, // comment
         int c  // comment
        ) ...
```

Is converted to

```
int Func(int a,  
         int b,  
         int c   
        ) ...
```

during the [third phase of translation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.phases#1.3).  If you wanted a single line equivelent before the translation phase happens then you need to use `/* */` like

```
    int Func(int a /*comment 1*/, int b /*comment 2*/, int c /*comment 3*/ ) ...
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)

> **5.7 Comments**
>
> > The characters // start a comment, which terminates immediately
> >     before the next new-line character ...

Therefore, after the comments have been striped out, the code finally interpreted by the compiler looks like this:

```
int Func(int a,
         int b,
         int c 
        ) {}
```

Even the newlines will stay intact.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are rather irrelevant for code, thus this code:

```
int Func(int a, // comment
         int b, // comment
         int c  // comment
        ) {}
```

is actually equivalent to this:

```
int Func(int a,
         int b,
         int c 
        ) {}
```

or if you want also this:

```
int Func(int a,int b,int c) {}
```

Single line comments starting with `//` end at the end of the line, hence putting code on the same line as a comment will turn the code into a comment and your two snippets are not equivalent.

Comment: "will turn the code into a comment" - That is what I thought it would have happened.

Comment: @Pietro and thats what is correct. Actually I missed the "Why does it build correctly (at least with G++)?" part of the question and tbh i dont belive that it does. Can you provide a [mcve]? If you have a line `int Func(int a` i cant imagine how this cannot be a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of comments:

- Comments that start with `//` are terminated at the end of the line
- Comments that start with `/*` are terminated by the next `*/`

The initial C specification only was aware of the `/* */` style comments.

The `//` style comments were introduced with C++ and also later in the C standard (not sure which one though).

So this:

```
int Func(int a, // comment
         int b, // comment
         int c  // comment
        ) ...
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int Func(int a, /* comment */
         int b, /* comment */
         int c  /* comment */
        ) ...
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
int Func(int a, /* comment */ int b, /* comment */ int c  /* comment */) ...
```